# redshift join tables using regex

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have 400 tables in redshift all of them have the same structure, and each table has a large number of records. Each table has the following columns: record_id, user_id, value.

all table names end with _values, Is there a way I can get all the unique users into one table, with an SQL query? Essentially is there a way to loop and join using regex.

Comment: I've never used redshift or postgresql, but I'd bet that the answer is to create a dynamic sql statement (or 400 of them with a union) to produce the users.  You would select from the metadata (sys.tables in tsql) and produce the sql you needed.

Comment: Yeah, That's what i was thinking, but lets see if there is a more cleaner way.